# Heating, and furnace making noise

Tags: furnace

Why does my Goodman gas furnace sound like a jet plane when the  burner  kicks on.My fan kicks on first,then the heat comes on,but sounds like a jet firing up.

Comment: The order of noises you should hear is - the exhaust blower spinning up, then the burners lighting, then the main air blower motor starting up. If the noise you note is before the burners light, it's probable that the bearings in the exhaust blower motor are going out.

Comment: Has it always done that or is it making new noises?